# Почему .toSortedMap() не работает

Tags: android, kotlin, map

В intellij idea, при использовании MutableMap, прекрасно работает toSortedMap, чтобы отсортировать её, но Android studio, мапа просто не сортируется, ошибок нет, всё работает, но не так, как надо

```
var buttons:MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf("sin" to 3, "cos" to 7, "log" to 5)
buttons.toSortedMap() //после этого действия ничего не меняется, а хотелось бы, чтобы отсортировалось по значению
```

Comment: добавьте информацию в вопрос, мало данных для размышлений и ответа!

Comment: А какую информацию, есть MutableMap<String, Int>, применяется toSortedMap, но с ничего не меняется

Comment: приведите код, желаемое поведение опишите и что вы для этого делали

Comment: Добавил изменения

Comment: есть гипотеза - проблема не в том как вы это делаете, а в том над чем производятся действия, другой вариант - вы используете не ту функцию

Comment: Скорей всего не ту функцию 0,потому что я пробовал и приравнивать и другие способы, но как тогда можно впринципе отсортировать map?

Comment: Ничего не происходить, потому что вы не сохраняете результат `buttons = buttons.toSortedMap()`

Comment: Пробовал, тоже ничего не происходит

Comment: Происходит, возвращается map структура, где сортируются ключи (строки в данном случае, а они сортируются в лексикографическом порядке). Результатом сортировки будет `{cos=7, log=5, sin=3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратимся к [документации](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-map-of.html), я бы сделал так:

```
var buttons = mutableMapOf(Pair("sin", 3), Pair("cos", 7), Pair("log", 5))
```

и дальше:

```
println(buttons.toList()
    .sortedBy { (key, value) -> value }
    .toMap())
```

и у вас в консоль выведет осортированный map.